# What's the difference between "I'm gonna be moving out" and "I'm going to move out"

Tags: grammar, difference

In season 6 of [friends](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108778/episodes?season=6) TV series, episode 2, in 4:03 Chandler says:
"I'm gonna be moving out." My question is, what's the difference between that sentence and the "I'm going to move out." Is there any difference between them?

Comment: No, there is not, but there is a difference between AE and BE, like there is a difference sometimes between how young people and older people use language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of "gonna" is informal speech meaning  "going to", so that makes no difference to the meaning.

"I'm going to move out" is a simple declaration of intention. It could be followed by a time qualifier: "tomorrow".

"I'm going to be moving out." is a little vaguer, and speaks of a process rather than an event, so it might take a little while to do it: "over the next week".

In practice, the meanings may be the same, depending on how they are qualified and the intention of the speaker.